# How collect data from unprotected sheets in the workbook in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I collect data from all the sheets of the table?

Through apps script, I get all the unprotected sheets on the book, and the width of the range with data on sheets with the same structure.

```
function GetRangeArray() { 
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var counter = 0;
  var StrRange = "";
  var Result = new Array();

  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {

    if (sheets[i].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0]){
      continue;
    };
    
    counter++;
    if ( counter == 1 ) {
      LastColumn = NumRetLetra(sheets[i].getLastColumn());
    }

        StrRange = "'" + sheets[i].getName() + "'!A2:" + LastColumn;
        Result.push([StrRange]); 
  }
    
  return Result;

function NumRetLetra(column){
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

On the protected "Total" sheet, I enter the formula into cell A1 =GetRangeArray().

```
=query({INDIRECT(A1);INDIRECT(A2)};"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

But I get an error: **The result is not fully displayed. Add rows (6) to the table.**

I try, where A1 - key, A3 - formula =GetRangeArray()

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1;A3);IMPORTRANGE(A1;A4)};"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

But I get an error: **The result is not fully displayed. Add rows (6) to the table.**

If i use:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1;A3)};"SELECT Col1, Col2")
```

or

```
=query({INDIRECT(A3)};"SELECT *")
```

This works, but only for one of the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you need to do, is to collect all data form all sheets, that is easy:

```js
function getAllData() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get active spreadsheet object.
  const sheets = sss.getSheets(); // get all sheet objects of the active spreadsheet as an array.
  const results = {}; // creat an object to hold the results.
  for (const sheet of sheets) { // use for...of loop to iterate the array of all sheets.
    const sheetName = sheet.getName(); // get the name of each sheet.
    results[sheetName] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // get all the data of each sheet, and put it into the results object with the sheet name as key.
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(restuls)); // show all data in you console.
}
```

Well, since you need to do the checking of protection, this would do:

```js
const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get active spreadsheet object.

function getAllData() {
  const sheets = sss.getSheets(); // get all sheet objects of the active spreadsheet as an array.
  const results = {}; // creat an object to hold the results.
  for (const sheet of sheets) { // use for...of loop to iterate the array of all sheets.
    const protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)[0]; // get protection statue.
    if (protection && !protection.canEdit()) continue; // if the page is protected, skip it.
    const sheetName = sheet.getName(); // get the name of each sheet.
    results[sheetName] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // get all the data of each sheet, and put it into the results object with the sheet name as key.
  }

  let maxLen = 0; // set a value to keep track of the longest row length.
  for(const value of Object.values(results)) { // iterate all data of each sheet.
    for(const row of value) { // iterate each row of the sheet values.
      if(row.length > maxLen) maxLen = row.length; // check if the length of row is bigger than the maxLen value, if true, replace that value.
      if(row.every(col => col === '')) continue; // if the row is empty, remove it.
    }
  }

  const resultArr = []; // set a place holder for the output 2D array.
  for(const value of Object.values(results)) { // iterate all data of each sheet again.
    for(const row of value) { // iterate each row of the sheet values again.
      if(maxLen > row.length) resultArr.push(row.concat(new Array(maxLen - row.length))); // if the length of a row is smaller than the maxLen value, insert empty values into the array.
      else resultArr.push(row); // push the row value to the output array place holder.
    }
  }

  return resultArr; // output to spreadsheet.
}
```

If you are calling function from the spreadsheet as a custome function, just modify your data structure into a 2D array, it can than be directly output to spreadsheet without doing all those indirect functions.

Comment: Something is wrong with declaring an array via 'const'. But the main idea is clear, and it's working.

Comment: @ITFAPK Good to know you managed to get this working. Just fixed the issues you have pointed out..I guess? Kinda hard to tell if I have missed anything without really running the code lol.

Answer (score 0):

Modified my script according to the answer above. It turned out the following:

```
function GetRangeArray() { 
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
    var sheetData = new Array();
    const Result = new Array();
    
    for (sheet of sheets) {
        if (sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0]) continue;
        sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        Object.values(sheetData).forEach(function (rowData, index) {
          if (index == 0) return; // without headers
          rowData.splice(1, 0, sheet.getName()); // sheet names as column for data indentify in total sheet.
          Result.push(rowData);
        });
      }
   return Result;
}
```